# How do I map a one to zero-or-one relationship in Entity Framework 4.2 when joining properties are of different types?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework 4.2 in a class library project. The database already exists, and I cannot modify it in any way whatsoever.

I have two model/domain classes that model two database tables. The tables both expose an Id column value, which I will refer to as ThingsId. Lets call the tables `TableOfThings1` and `TableOfThings2`. Here are my classes:

```
public class TableOfThings1
{
    public string ThingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Thing Thing { get; set; }
}

public class TableOfThings2 //qse
{
    public Int64? ThingId {get; set;}
    public string ThingName { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that the `TableOfThings1` exposes ThingsId as a nullable varchar(64), while `TableOfThings2` exposes ThingsId as a non-nullable bigint.

How can I tell the Entity Framework to join on these two keys? I have tried using this:

```
HasOptional(things1 => things1.thing).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.ThingId);
```

in the `EntityTypeConfiguration` for`TableOfThings1`.

I have also tried casting in the middle of that statement, which does not work. Using the setup shown above gets me this error message currently:

> "The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential
>   constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the
>   Principal Role".

Does anyone know for sure whether/how this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with EF. You can not even create a foreign key in the database if the column types are different. Possible workaround would be to create a view of `TableOfThings1` with `ThingId` column type matching the `TableOfThings2`s column type.

Comment: @DanM Model validation performed by EF rejects this type of inconsistencies. Poorly designed schemas are difficult to map with EF

Comment: We had this working with a "CTP" version of the entity framework's DLL using this:

    HasOptional(thing1 => thing1.Thing).WithMany().HasConstraint((thing1, thing2) => thing1.ThingId == thing2.Id);

But, `HasConstraint` has been replaced with `HasForeignKey`, and now that setup doesn't work. We had the `TableOfThings2.ThingId` defined as a string, which worked in conjunction with the `HasOptional` line above -- i.e., it compiled, built, ran, etc. 

With 4.2 DLL we get: The `ThingId` property on `TableOfThings2` could not be set to a `Int64`...set this to a non-null value of type 'String'.